# Will pushing data through an XML parser perform validation acording to this specification?

Tags: xml, validation

I am working on a system that states that this is the only allowed input:

```
The following Unicode characters are allowed:
#x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF
Any characters not included in this list will be rejected. 
For more information, see the http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets
```

I need to validate my data to match the specification given above.

I started to write code to evaluate my data character by character, then it occurred to me that perhaps this is exactly the same as the data allowed by XML.

So I thought instead, how about I just push the data into an XML parser and if no invalid token errors then the validation is done.

So I wrote some code to insert my data into a CDATA element in a minimal XML document and then parse the data and that is fine - it works, no problem.

But I am wondering, have I achieved my goal?  Does running my data through an XML parser ensure that it meets the specification above? I believe so because the "for more information" link above seems to reiterate that the defined unicode characters are those allowed in XML.

But I thought I'd better ask because it's still an assumption on my part that a successful XML parse means the document passes the validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is well formed, then it will be valid according to your requirement.

Note that a  'valid' xml document usually implies that it is valid according to an XSD or DTD, which is not what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will reject a string that contains the sequence "]]>". I can't see an easy way around that. But it seems a rather heavy-handed approach anyway: isn't it simpler just to apply a regular expression?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Maybe I'll strip the sequence "]]>" before parsing.

Comment: >>  "isn't it simpler just to apply a regular expression?" .... I figured that parsing is simpler and faster because the XML parser is written in C, and I don't have to write a regex that is possibly buggy.

Comment: If speed is important, then instantiating an XML parser is the last thing you want to do. The character scan will be fast, but the start-up overhead will be high.

Comment: I found a regex to do the job here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098886/will-pushing-data-through-an-xml-parser-perform-validation-acording-to-this-spec  interestingly the performance of the regex is almost exactly the same as pushing the data through an XML parser to do the validation.